# inputaccessoryview not showing (StoryBoard)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview, xcode5

I have been trying to incorporate a `UIView`/`Toolbar` above my keyboard but have had no luck. When I added a toolbar it was scrambled so thus I need to put it into a `UIView` but the `UIView` does not want to appear above the keyboard. Code Below:

My Header:

```
 @property (nonatomic, Strong) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIToolbar *TitleBar;
 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *AddView;
```

The `ViewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{      
    // observe keyboard hide and show notifications to resize the text view appropriately
    /*[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
     */

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
        // iOS 7
        [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
    } else {
        // iOS 6
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    }

    self.attributionTitle.delegate = self;
    self.attribution.delegate = self;
    textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    // quoteText.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    // quoteText.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

    // textView.delegate = self;   // code or in IB

    [textView becomeFirstResponder];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

The `textViewDidBeginEditing`:

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    self.textView.inputAccessoryView = self.AddView;
}
```

Here is to show the `UIView` is connected:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the `textView.inputAccessoryView = AddView;`to the `ViewDidLoad`then deleted the view from my storyboard and remade it. Lastly I added the `UIView` to the bottom black bar.

Comment: What does it mean you added the view to the bottom black bar? Is it possible to define a view in a storyboard that is not actually placed in the view controller that owns it? Where does such a view visually appear in the storyboard and is it linked to the parent view controller by some segue?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `inputAccessoryView` in `textViewDidBeginEditing` is probably too late. The input accessory view should be set before that, e.g., in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Try something like:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

UIView

    myTextField.inputAccessoryView = [self accessoryViewWithPreviousEnabled:NO nextEnabled:YES];

    // more stuff as required...
}
```

And a method for creating a previous/next button (you'll need to provide your own images for the buttons and implements the `previousAccessoryViewButtonTapped:` and `previousAccessoryViewButtonTapped:` methods). It takes two `BOOL` parameters to indicate if the previous and/or next buttons should be enabled.

```
#pragma mark - Accessory view methods

-(UIView *)accessoryViewWithPreviousEnabled:(BOOL)previousEnabled nextEnabled:(BOOL)nextEnabled{
    previousButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    previousButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 2, 60, 30);
    [previousButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:PREVIOUS_BUTTON] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    previousButton.enabled = previousEnabled;
    [previousButton addTarget:self action:@selector(previousAccessoryViewButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    nextButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    nextButton.frame = CGRectMake(80, 2, 60, 30);
    [nextButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NEXT_BUTTON] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    nextButton.enabled = nextEnabled;
    [nextButton addTarget:self action:@selector(nextAccessoryViewButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIView *transparentBlackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 34)];
    transparentBlackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.f green:0.f blue:0.f alpha:0.6f];

    UIView *accessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 34)];
    [accessoryView addSubview:transparentBlackView];
    [accessoryView addSubview:previousButton];
    [accessoryView addSubview:nextButton];

    return accessoryView;
}
```

Note this method is hard coded for an iPad in landscape orientation. You need to change it for an iPhone.

Comment: Is it possible to set it up in a storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `self.AddView` is already in your interface (because you put it there, in the storyboard). It can't be in two places at once.